# Libgdx Reading External Resources

Tags: android, libgdx

In desktop application I can load a texture like this

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.absolute("C:/picture.png"));
```

How can I do this in android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**external** is relative to your sd card. So this:

```
Texture texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.external("picture.png"));
```

will look in the root of the sd card.